# Perl compare array values with values in a hash of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

This post has been updated based on comments and answer by DVK

I have changed to using the 3-argument form of open and correctly pushed IDs into the array

updated code below

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;


my $file1 = "Inputfile.txt";
my $file2 = $ARGV[0];
my $file3 = $ARGV[1];

open (OF, " > Results.txt") or die "Can't write new file: $!";

my %hash;
open(INPUT1, "<" , $file1)or die("Failed to open file1: $!");
while (!eof(INPUT1)) {
    my @elements = split(/\t/, <INPUT1>);
    my $F1catagory = $elements[2];
    my $F1IDs = $elements[3];
    push @{$hash{$F1catagory}}, $F1IDs;
}
close(INPUT1);

my @array1;
open(INPUT2, "<" , $file2) or die ("Failed to open file2: $!");
while (!eof(INPUT2)) {
    my @line = split(/\t/, <INPUT2>);
    my $F2catagory = $line [0];
    my $F2IDs    = $line [1];
    push (@array1, $F2IDs);
}
print OF @array1;
close(INPUT2);

my @array2;
open(INPUT3, "<" , $file3) or die ("Failed to open file3: $!");
while (!eof(INPUT3)) {
    my @lines = split(/\t/, <INPUT3>);
    my $F3catagory     = $lines [0];
    my $F3IDs = $lines [1];
    push (@array2, $F3IDs );


}
print OF @array2;
close(INPUT3);
```

Input data looks like

The following

file 1  contains Information about processes looks like the below the 3rd column contains the process ID and the 4th column contains the Item ID (these are used to create my %hash)

```
process 9606    0051712 3458    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051712 2208    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051712 2150    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051712 4843    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0032513 2280    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0032513 2281    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 23583   [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 6996    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 4913    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 10309   [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 4350    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 4968    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 4595    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0006285 8930    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051503 284439  [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051503 2697    [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051503 291 [25 Jul 2011]
process 9606    0051503 10478   [25 Jul 2011]
```

file2 contains the catagory of the item in column1 and the Item ID in column 2

```
CS1G2   1455
TM65    157378
PFN1    5216
HUL1    11100
ERI3    79033
PR12    57479
HIFN    55662
HNPD    3184
 HI2    28996
 LD1    84316
GRB2    2885
 AL6    84964
PCM1    5108
 ZN7    126208
MAK2    5605
BCL3    602
```

file 3 is the the same as file 2 except the item IDs are different

I need to find out if any of the proceses in file 1 contain items from both file 2 and file 3.

I hope this makes the question clearer

#######original question

I am having some trouble with a script I’ve been trying to write

I have a file containing process information I have read the process ID and the Item ID into a hash of arrays with the process IDs as keys and the Item IDs as the values (Hash of arrays as multiple Item in a single process)

I have two arrays of Item ID 
@F2IDs and @F3IDs

If there are any Item IDs that are in both @F2IDs and @F3IDs in the same process (in the same value of %hash) I want to identify it is in the same process

I have this code so far

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file1 = "Infile.txt";
my $file2 = $ARGV[0];
my $file3 = $ARGV[1];

open (OF, " > Results.txt") or die "Can't write new file: $!";


my %hash;
open(INPUT, $file1)or die("Failed to open file2");
while (!eof(INPUT)) {
    my @elements = split(/\t/, <INPUT>);
    my $F1catagory = $elements[2];
    my $F1IDs = $elements[3];
    push @{$hash{$catagory}}, $F1IDs;
}
close(INPUT);

open(INPUT, $file2) or die "Can't write new file: $!";
while (!eof(INPUT)) {
    my @line = split(/\t/, <INPUT>);
    my $F2catagory = $line [0];
    my @F2IDs    = $line [1];
}
close(INPUT);

open(INPUT, $file3) or die "Can't write new file: $!";
while (!eof(INPUT)) {
    my @lines = split(/\t/, <INPUT>);
    my @F3catagory     = $lines [0];
    my @F3IDs = $lines [1];
}
close(INPUT);
```

I need to do something like the Pseudo code below but don’t know if there is an "if in" construct in perl like there is in python

```
$insameprocess = False;
foreach value in %hash;
    if F2IDs and F3IDs are in {$hash{$catagory}};;
       $insameprocess = True;
       print OF "the key the value and if they are in the same process";
```

Has any one got any ideas on how to do this in perl?

Thanks in advance for help
Regards

S

Comment: As an unrelated side note, the way you use `open` is insecure and can lead to bugs due to use of global filehandles. Please use the 3-argument form with lexical filehandles instead: `open(my $input, "<" , $file1 ) or die("Failed to open $file1: $!");
`

Comment: Could you also please give example of contents of your input data and output data and expected results? The word description is a little confusing.

Comment: I have edited m question to account for these comments. Can you help me out any further? I think the question is clearer now. Thank you so much for your help so far. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around perl.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 problems:

1. In general, your script seems to contain a lot of bugs in reading the data. I won't cover that for now since that isn't what you asked about. For example, you need to push IDs into arrays in loops 2/3 instead of assigning to an array (you do it correctly in the first loop).
2. Your main technical question seems to be"how to tell if some ID in a hash value (which is an array ref)?".

   The BEST way to approach that is to store the data in a hashref of IDs (mapped to "1") instead of an arrayref of IDs, and use hash lookups:

   ```
   # This is in your first loop reading file 1
   # OLD CODE:    push @{$hash{$catagory}}, $F1IDs;
   # NEW CODE:
   # # Each hash value is a hashref, with keys being IDsx and values simply 1
   $hash{$catagory}->{$F1IDs} = 1; 

   # This is the code in the end, to check if some ID is in the hash:
   if ($hash{$catagory}->{$F1IDs}) {
       # $id_is_in_hash = 1;
   }
   ```
3. Frankly, your pseudocode doesn't make too much sense to me (nor your description) so I can't help you with writing a complete check replacing your pseudocode using my solution from bullet point #2. If you can provide either more explicit description, or better yet example data in 3 files and desired output, I'll be able to do more.